# What window.postMessage emulation options are there for IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, postmessage

I'm aware of the hacks using hash tags, however, I need bi-directional communication with larger payloads and higher throughput.  Are there any Flash/ActiveX/etc options that make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery windowMsg plugin provides a good all browser compliant solution.

See an example:

http://iterativo.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/using-jquery-to-communicate-between-browser-windows/

A link to the plugin code:

http://go-trendy.com/javascripts/jquery.windowmsg-1.0.js?1279359701

Comment: But be aware that solution only works if both windows are on the same domain, protocol, and port.

Comment: @robocat That's actually a huge limitation, since IMO `postMessage` is mostly useful in dodging cross-domain issues. If it's not cross-domain, you can just call JavaScript directly on the other page and be done with it.

Comment: @jdmichal - yeah - the code is very limited. postMessage is very useful for cross domain. Also note postMessage is available in IE8 even if IE8 is in IE7 mode!

Comment: @robocat That IE7 mode thing is actually a really cool factoid. I would not have expected that to be the case.

Comment: @jdmichal - I was pleasantly surprised. It might be there in other modes too (quirks, IE6), but I haven't tested it. Of course, it is just another example of why feature detection is much preferable to browser sniffing when possible.

Answer (score 0):

[EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) is the closest I can think of, although it isn't a postMessage() polyfill, so would need a lot of work. Also as at Sept 2012, there is a note saying that EasyXDM isn't working for IE6/IE7 - YMMV.