# Is postMessage()-usage limited to HTML5 documents?

Tags: postmessage

we are developing a webapp and we are using xhtml documents. We ran into same-origin-policy-issues and now we are wondering if postMessage() could fit our needs?

Anyway, we won't be able to switch to HTML5! Can we use use postMessage()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postMessage() alternative for ie6/7 between iFrames and/or pop ups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121435/postmessage-alternative-for-ie6-7-between-iframes-and-or-pop-ups)